# allow clicking of child element in div with overlaying link

Tags: jquery, css

So basically, I have a jQuery accordion. I arranged the content so that it appears inside bounding box (header) of the accordion. I have several items that have `href`'s tied to them within the content. Problem is that I can't click through the accordion header because it is also clickable obviously.

It looks like this:

```
---------------------------
- (top layer)             -
-                         -
-   ------------------    -
-   - (bottom layer) -    -
-   - click me!      -    -
-   ------------------    -
-                         -
---------------------------
```

So I can just bind a click event to the bottom layer but I'd really love to avoid doing so. What are the options?

Comment: Probably using some sort of stopPropagation will work, but there is no code posted, so it's impossible to tell really!

Comment: Not sure I got the question, but are you trying to click on elements that are behind other elements, if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from http://cmar.me/2011/06/15/links-in-jquery-accordion-headers/

```
$('content .image a').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;
});
```

Not what was originally requested but simple enough to live with.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent it by `OnClick="preventAction(event)"` and in JS

```
function preventAction(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I should be more clear. The top level is not an `href`, just a regular div, `preventDefault()` will have no effect I think.